# How to set an input field value from ajax generated unordered list with Selenium Webdriver (C#)?

Tags: c#, html, .net, ajax, selenium-webdriver

The form input has the following html structure.

```
<span>
    <input type="hidden" name="color">
    <!-- start async created -->
    <ul>
        <li value="green">Green</li>
        <li value="blue">Blue</li>
        <li value="red">Red</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- end async created -->
</span>
```

As you could see it's not a classic form select, but an unordered list (ul) which is asynchroon created. I need to choose one of the items from the ul. Does anyone know how to do that with Selenium Webdriver (C#)?

Thanks a lot,
Jordy

Comment: How would a real user do it?

Comment: A real user enters a color in a textbox with name "entered-color". After entering 3 characters a prefill list is on screen (see above code example). The user selects one color and that will be setted to the hidden field with name "color".

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started:

```
var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(25));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("...");

// enter the color
driver.FindElementByCssSelector("[name='entered-color']").SendKeys("Blu");

// select the color
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("li[value='blue']"))).Click();
```

Comment: The solution is really close now. I get an error on the latest line: Element is not clickable at point (362.5, 20). Other element would receive the click:

Comment: Try with ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable instead of ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible

Comment: That does not solve the issue. The element is not clickable. It's an item from an unordered list, not an item from a selectbox. Any idea?

Comment: Try to wait for an attribute that is different once the list is display.

Answer (score 0):

you can marked the `li` element,  where the value equal with the value of the input.

JS code (you should include `jquery` in html head )

```
$("input").change(function(event) {

    $("ul li:contains('"+$("input").val()+"')").addClass("selected");//if the inpute's value changed then the li will added a class attribute corresponding

});
```